# how to use javaxt in JSP

Tags: jsp, jar, web-inf

[image]i want to use Javaxt libs in JSP code

so i contain external libs in my DynamicWebProject

and use like this

```
<%@ page import="javaxt.io.Image"%>
<%
    javaxt.io.Image image = new javaxt.io.Image(
            "C:\\codeTest\\test.jpg");
    double[] gps = image.getGPSCoordinate();
    out.println(gps[1]);
    out.println(gps[0]);
%>
```

this code is work fine at JAVA project but can't work at JSP web

how to use javaxt in JSP?

Comment: add the lib in WEB-INF/libs and you should be through

Comment: @Sataya you mean just put in file in WEB-INF/libs? but it didn't work

Comment: @Sataya and i import lib in my porject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All webapp-specific runtime dependencies need to go in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

However, for some unclear reason you named that folder `/WEB-INF/libs`. This is obviously wrong.

Rename it back to `/WEB-INF/lib` and then it should end up correctly in webapp's runtime classpath. It's already the default folder name when you create a *Dynamic Web Project* from scratch. You're not supposed to rename those generated folders.

Also make sure that you don't touch anything in project's *Build Path* property, otherwise things may still possibly fail. Just dropping the JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder ought to be sufficient.